# Tablesorter - sort by td class

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am trying to use tablesorter to sort a column by class.  The class will determine the background image to indicate true/false.

The two types of class within the column will be:

```
<td class='icon silk-cross'>
<td class='icon silk-tick'>
```

I've tried this code as a custom parser but have not come up with a working solution.

```
  $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'truefalse',
    is: function(s) {
      return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell) {
      var $cell = $(cell);
      return $cell.attr('class') || s;
    },
    type: 'text'
  });
```

Is there a way to access the attributes of each cell?

**EDIT:** jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/LtyMN/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to include the new parser in the `headers` option ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/LtyMN/3/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'truefalse',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
        var $cell = $(cell);
        return $cell.attr('class') || s;
    },
    type: 'text'
});

$("table").tablesorter({
    headers : {
        2: { sorter: 'truefalse' }
    },
    widgets: ['zebra']
});
```

Please note that if you use the `updateCell` method, it won't provide the `cell` argument properly to the parser format function. I have fixed this issue in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/).

Comment: Excellent, this worked like a charm and the jsfiddle helped me realize the column index starts at zero since I could see your markup. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If this may help.

```
   $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} );
```

Click on any th(head) that will be sorted, :)

fiddle for the same : 
[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/LtyMN/1/)

I hope this will do

without visible number:
[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LtyMN/2/)

Enjoy :)

Comment: I'd like to sort by the class of the cell in the trufalse column.  This will display a tick or cross as the background image.

Comment: I only want to display images, not text (eg. 0/1)

Comment: I tried that but as we are using two class it will not work always, some browser may disturb its working. Will look for another solution after some time :)

Comment: Thanks for trying, that is a solution I had considered.  However, I would specifically like to sort on the td's 'class'.  Adding a hidden span to every row of my database will cause significant bloat.

Comment: to reduce that yo umay use <b class=hid>0</b>

but then also it will consume some space :)